# Java-8 way to access an ArrayList using a configurable BatchSize

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream

Here is my use case:
I have a responseList of Strings which consist of 1000 records. There is a configurable batchSize. I have to iterate responseList, and for every split=batch size, I have to construct the DataResponseBean and publishToKafka.

For example, if my responseList.size=1000 and batchSize=100, I will construct DataResponseBean and publish data to Kafka 10 times instead of 1000 times. Also, if any exception is thrown in publishToKafka, I should break the stream and stop processing responseList.

I need help on converting this to Java 8 style(The way I'm iterating the list and incrementing the page-number.

```java
public class DataResponseBean {
    List<String> data;
    
    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MetaData getMetaData() {
        return metaData;
    }

    public void setMetaData(MetaData metaData) {
        this.metaData = metaData;
    }

    MetaData metaData;

}
```

```java
public class MetaData {

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public int getPageNumber() {
        return pageNumber;
    }

    public void setPageNumber(int pageNumber) {
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    }

    String orderId;
     int pageNumber;
}
```

Here is my Java 7 style of code:

```java
import model.DataResponseBean;
import model.MetaData;

import java.util.*;
        
public class TestJavaClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> dataList= Arrays.asList("jony","rakshi","raman","reka","nency","raman","rishi");
        String orderId="12345";
        int pageNumber=0;
        int batchSize=2;
        int currentBatchSize=0;
        List<String> batch=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String data:dataList){
            try{
                batch.add(data);
                currentBatchSize++;
                if(currentBatchSize>=batchSize){
                    DataResponseBean dataResponseBean=new DataResponseBean();
                    MetaData metaData=new MetaData();
                    dataResponseBean.setData(batch);
                    metaData.setOrderId(orderId);
                    metaData.setPageNumber(pageNumber);
                    dataResponseBean.setMetaData(metaData);
                    publishToKafka(dataResponseBean);
                    batch.clear();
                    pageNumber++;
                    currentBatchSize=0;
    
                }
    
             }
    
             DataResponseBean dataResponseBean=new DataResponseBean();
             MetaData metaData=new MetaData();
             dataResponseBean.setData(batch);
             metaData.setOrderId(orderId);
             metaData.setPageNumber(pageNumber);
             dataResponseBean.setMetaData(metaData);
             publishToKafka(dataResponseBean);
             batch.clear();
        }catch(Exception e){
            batch.clear();
            break;
        }
            
    }

    private static void publishToKafka(DataResponseBean dataResponseBean) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("----------RESPONSE start================-");
        System.out.println("-----------"+dataResponseBean.getMetaData().getPageNumber());
        List<String> dataList=dataResponseBean.getData();
        dataList.forEach(data->{
            System.out.println("------data-----"+data);
        });
    }
}
```

Please help me to convert this code into Java 8 style. I am very new to Java 8.

[ **Note** :For some issue in my current workspace Lombok was not working. I will be using Lombok for DataResponseBean and MetaData]

Comment: There is no reason to turn this into “Java 8 style”. But even with Java 7 (in fact with all Java versions since Java 2), it would be more efficient to use `subList` instead of looping over the elements and copying them into another list.

Answer (score 2):

You should not think in terms of “Java 7 style” and “Java 8 style”. Valid Java 7 code is also valid Java 8 code. Instead, strive for readability and efficiency.

Your code loops over the list’s elements and copies them into a new, temporary list. This is unnecessary. Instead, use `subList`

```java
for(int pageNumber=0, s = 0, e, size = dataList.size(); s < size; s = e, pageNumber++) {
    e = Math.min(s + batchSize, size);
    DataResponseBean dataResponseBean=new DataResponseBean();
    MetaData metaData=new MetaData();
    dataResponseBean.setData(dataList.subList(s, e));
    metaData.setOrderId(orderId);
    metaData.setPageNumber(pageNumber);
    dataResponseBean.setMetaData(metaData);
    publishToKafka(dataResponseBean);
}
```

You can express the same as a Stream operation

```java
IntStream.range(0, (dataList.size() + batchSize - 1) / batchSize)
    .mapToObj(pageNumber -> {
        int s = pageNumber * batchSize, e = Math.min(s + batchSize, dataList.size());
        DataResponseBean dataResponseBean=new DataResponseBean();
        MetaData metaData=new MetaData();
        dataResponseBean.setData(dataList.subList(s, e));
        metaData.setOrderId(orderId);
        metaData.setPageNumber(pageNumber);
        dataResponseBean.setMetaData(metaData);
        return dataResponseBean;
    })
    .forEach(dataResponseBean -> publishToKafka(dataResponseBean));
```

but there is no advantage in doing so. What harms readability most, is the fact that your `MetaData` and `DataResponseBean` classes seem to have neither, an appropriate constructor nor a builder, requiring you to instantiate them via default constructor and perform a series of `set…` method calls.

It should be easily recognizable that those calls dominate the code.

Comment: Thanks @Holger for the advice.Ya readability of my code was not good.Another advce.The publishToKafka  is having exception.If any exception is thrown inside publishtOkafka,I should  stop processing stream further.How to handle exception here